# Find what genre is most frequent in each age category

Tags: mysql

I am thinking about making age groups per decade and find out what genre is more frequent. It is more difficult than I expected but here is what I have tried:

One table is like this, called: `sell_log`

```
id id_film id_cust
1   2      2
2   3      4
3   1      5
4   4      3
5   5      1
6   2      4
7   2      3
8   3      1
9   5      3
```

2nd here is a table about the `films` that has the id and the genres:

```
id_film      genres
    1        comedy
    2        fantasy
    3        sci-fi
    4        drama
    5        thriller
```

and 3rd table, `customers` is this:

```
id_cust  date_of_birth_cust
1          1992-03-12
2          1999-06-25
3          1986-01-14
4          1985-09-18
5          1992-05-19
```

This is the code I did:

```
select  id_cust,date_of_birth_cust,
    CASE
    WHEN date_of_birth_cust > 1980-01-01 and date_of_birth_cust < 1990-01-01 then ##show genre##
    WHEN date_of_birth_cust > 1990-01-01 and date_of_birth_cust < 2000-01-01 then ##show genre##
    ELSE ##show genre##
    END
from purchases 
INNER JOIN (
    select  id_cust 
    FROM sell_log
    group by id_cust
  ) customer.id_cust = sell_log.id_cust
```

How is the correct form in your opinion?

Expected results: for example
based on the most frequent number of genres find that genre and pass it for that age group.

```
ages                most frequent genre
from 1980 to 1990     comedy
from 1990 to 2000     fantasy
rest ages             drama
```

Update:
doing the code in the answer gives this:

```
ages                most_frequent_genre
from 1980 to 1989   Comedy
from 1990 to 1999   Thriller
from 1990 to 1999   Action
from 1990 to 1999   Comedy
rest                Comedy
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: What is your expected results?

Comment: I have added an expected result. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you understand the problem now?

Comment: What is the version of MySql?

Comment: the version is 8

Comment: how can `rest ages             drama` be in the expected results ? With those CASE expression filters and or example data..

Comment: 'from purchases ' what table is that then?

Comment: Has anyone ever made a sci-fi comedy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`CTE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to get the results per age and genre and then use it to get the maximum number of purchases per age. Finally join again to the CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select 
    CASE
      WHEN year(c.date_of_birth_cust) between 1980 and 1989 then 'from 1980 to 1989'
      WHEN year(c.date_of_birth_cust) between 1990 and 1999 then 'from 1990 to 1999'
      ELSE 'rest'
    END ages,
    f.genres,
    count(*) counter
  from sell_log s
  inner join films f on f.id_film = s.id_film 
  inner join customers c on c.id_cust = s.id_cust
  group by ages, f.genres
)

select c.ages, c.genres most_frequent_genre
from cte c inner join (
  select c.ages, max(counter) counter 
  from cte c
  group by c.ages
) g on g.ages = c.ages and g.counter = c.counter
order by c.ages
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kdL7ArrRA9TvQkTj5H2AdK/4).
In your sample data there are ties which will all be at the results.
Results:

```
| ages              | most_frequent_genre |
| ----------------- | ------------------- |
| from 1980 to 1989 | fantasy             |
| from 1990 to 1999 | comedy              |
| rest              | fantasy             |
```

Comment: WOW, CTE'S? I will check it soon when I finish another task. Can it also be solved with 'case' like I tried?  Also since this is for practice and learning, can you explain a bit the thinking process to solve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: The CTE joins the 3 tables and with grouping the rows by age it counts the number of purchases per age and genre. Then from this resultset in the main body of the query again by grouping I get the maximum number of purchases per age and genre. Then by joining again to the cte I get only the rows corresponding to that maximum number. If this number belongs to more than 1 genres for an age then all these genres will be returned.

Comment: this one is close only problem is the the CTE case matches all, the `rest ages -> drama` is not showing, but i think it more the case that the topicstarter has made a unlogical expected result..

Comment: @RaymondNijland there are not any rows for the `rest` case in the sample data. Did you try it with other data and it did not work?

Comment: iam not the topicstarter , but like i said (in a comment edit) the topicstarter made most likely a  unlogical expected result as it not possible with those CASE expression filters and example data that `rest ages -> drama` is there

Comment: (I know you are not the topic starter) yes, the sample data from the question and 1 row that I added in my fiddle do not contain that category.

Comment: I edited the fiddle and the question to include this category.

Comment: the data in the expected result are just an example, not the actual result, more like how it would look like.

Comment: I added 2 rows in my demo fiddle, just to cover also the `rest` case.

Comment: I studied your answer and the site with your example and it looks accurate but I got strange results. Can you check the updated question with the result I received?

Comment: They are not "strange". For the age `from 1990 to 1999` there is not a single favorite. There are 3 because of the ties in purchases.

Comment: Correct. Do you know why it takes so long to run that query and it causes MySQL to stop and I have to restart every time?

Comment: less than 30. When I restart it returns it immediately. But if I run it again it crashes again after a few seconds and I have to restart again.

Comment: The this is a problem of the ide you're using. If you see my demo, it runs without any problems.